# How to style each table cell in a column via CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have an ordinary HTML table:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="first-column-style">FAT</td> 
    <td>...</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="first-column-style">FAT</td>
    <td>...</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I want to apply CSS style to every table cell (`td`) in a particular column. Is it possible to do that without applying the `class`/`style` attribute to every table cell in that column, and without JavaScript?

Comment: this seems to actually be the better solution, given the limitations of the other approaches

Comment: None of these solutions are acceptable; it looks like there is currently no single way to specify a column's cell properties because there is nowhere to add a class or id to a column. It is my opinion that this feature should not have been deprecated without a generic alternative. There is absolutely no reasonable justification for forcing coders to know the numerical index of a html table or specify a class in every table cell in order to style it.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Use the `<col>` tag and style it following [this guide](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/columns.html). This way you only need to add a class (or inline style specification) to the `<col>` element instead of each `<td>` in the table.

**Caveats:**

- Any row or cell styling will supersede column styling.
- The `<col>` tag only supports styling `border`, `background`, `width` and `visibility` (and their derivatives, such as `background-color`).
- The `border` declaration does not work unless the `<table>` has `border-collapse: collapse;`, and the behavior is inconsistent between browsers.
- The `visibility` declaration does not work properly in Chrome due to a [known bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=174167).

Comment: note: <col> accepts only a few style properties (like text-align or width)

Comment: This is still the best solution for the styles it will address because the style and markup remain independent. The more accepted answer below is necessary, but fragile because adding a column to market would completely break the intended result so it requires more maintenance.

Comment: As I understand it, it requires the markup to use columns instead of rows. So it prevents to style rows at the same time.

Comment: Almost all `<col>` attributes are also not supported in HTML5: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_col.asp

Comment: @AlanH It's because HTML5 expects you to use CSS3 instead of such attributes, so they got deprecated. The important attributes `span`, `style` and `class` are still available in HTML5.

Comment: @fcalderan It doesn't even support `text-align`. The only things it supports are `border`, `background`, `width` and `visibility` (and their derivatives, if any). This makes this `col` tag pretty useless. You're better off just putting a class on your `th/td` and styling that class without such stupid limitations. Or you can use the `child` hacks.

Comment: I think the linked guide is wrong, as `<col>` is supposed to be used within a `<colgroup>` block. See HMTL standard: https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/tabular-data.html#the-col-element

Comment: Not working when style is applied on generic `td` tag. E.g. `background-color` on `td` takes preference over local style on `col` tag.

Answer (score 94):

This is a 2015 answer and based on the first-child answer but MUCH cleaner.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child

```
td:nth-child(1) { /* first column */ }
td:nth-child(2) { /* second column */ }
td:nth-child(3) { /* third column */ }
```

Super clean code

Comment: I agree, this should be the current solution.

Comment: This may not give the desired results if your table uses colspan.

Comment: Both colspan and rowspan will cause major problems.  When you use either span, the sibling of the 'spans' don't exist, so you'll end up styling the wrong cells.

Comment: If, for some weird reason, you have non-<td> tags between the <td> tags, you'll need to use nth-of-type instead.

Comment: This is ideal for most cases. Though it may come back to bite you if you ever want to later reorder your columns in a large table. Then you'd need to use a script to change the indices of all the `nth-child` declarations in your code. In such cases, using the `col` tag would be best. Unfortunately there seem to be issues with that tag, as some have noted.

Comment: Nah, it's too clean. I don't know why we can't have like `td:thirty-first-child {}` It would be so human-readable and intuitive ;-p

Answer (score 69):

Additionally to Sean Patrick Floyd's solution you can combine `:first-child` with the adjacent sibling selector `+` (also not supported by IE6):

```
td:first-child { /* first column */ }

td:first-child + td { /* second column */ }

td:first-child + td + td { /* third column */ }

/* etc. */
```

Comment: I upvoted this and the <col> solution noting that WHEN it can be used, <col class=""> is the better solution (see my comment there for explanation).

Comment: Not that this doesn't work with `colspan`, as it is just counting `<td>` children of `<tr>` and not actual columns.  You might be able to work around by using a css selector that selects classes of rows to apply the column hack to: `tr.myclass td:first-child { ... }`

Answer (score 19):

Well for the first and last columns you can use the `:first-child` and `:last-child` pseudo class:

```
/* make the first cell of every row bold */
tr td:FIRST-CHILD{
    font-weight:bold;
}

/* make the last cell of every row italic */
tr td:LAST-CHILD{
    font-style:italic;
}
```

### Reference:

- [:first-child and :last-child](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/firstchild.html)

Comment: `:first-child` is only [almost supported](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html) by IE8 and `:last-child` is not supported at all.

Comment: Same old song. Sorry, haven't used IE in years. Works like a charm in FF and Chrome.

Comment: A Downvote? why? This is a valid CSS solution. You should send your downvotes to Redmond for building buggy browsers ...

Comment: Sean Patrick Floyd: That's like saying that you SHOULD be able to walk around naked because it's someone elses problem if they don't like it. Ideals and reality are not one in the same. "Valid CSS" is css that both meets the rules AND works.

Comment: @rainabba: and MS (by virtue of IE) defines the rule set? I think not. If a feature is supported in CSS but not in a browser, it is not the solution that fails.

Comment: I imagine the downvote is because this is a solution to a question that was not asked - the poster wants to style ANY column, based on class, not the first or last column (or any indexed column for that matter). The column position/index is extra data that is not known.

Answer (score 4):

The following allows you to style columns at table level, and can be used in a more general way to the previous examples, as you don't have to make assumptions about the styles applied to a given column index within the style sheet itself.

I agree that the <col>  approach is best if it fits your needs, but the range of styles is very limited.

The sample styles column 1, 2, & 4 with a grey text style.

**HTML**

```
<table class="example col1-readonly col2-readonly col4-readonly">
```

**CSS**

```
.example.col1-readonly tr td:nth-child(1),
.example.col2-readonly tr td:nth-child(2),
.example.col3-readonly tr td:nth-child(3),
.example.col4-readonly tr td:nth-child(4) {
    color:#555;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this improves anything - the actual index number is not known, the solution needs to use a *class* for identifying the column position.