# How to apply red color font to specific column for dynamic data?

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular-material, angular7, angular-components

I work on angular 7 app I need to apply red color font to data content body to  `columnname='onlineurl'.

but I don't know how to do that?

I show data dynamically meaning no fixed column or data and code below working without any issue.

My main thing I need is if `columnname='onlineurl'` make font color to content body data red.

my code as below 
data source on ts as below:

```
this._displayreport.GetReportDetailsPaging(this.searchData).subscribe((data: any[]) => {  

       this.reportdetailslist = data;  

       this.headerCols = Object.keys(data[0]);  

       data.forEach((item) =>{  
         let values = Object.keys(item).map((key)=> item[key])

         this.contentBody.push(values);  


  });  


     });
```

to get header without data I do as below:

```
<thead style="width: max-content">    
         <tr>    
           <th  *ngFor="let coln of headerCols">    

               {{coln}}    

           </th> 
 </tr>    


         </tr>   
</thead>
```

to get content data without header I do

```
<tr *ngFor="let rep of contentBody">    

                <td *ngFor="let r1 of rep"><span>{{r1}}</span></td>    

                <td
</tr> 
Result Returned 
ReportId   onlineurl          reportdate
1222       localhost:5000/    12-12-2018
1255       localhost:7000/    12-01-2019
1230       localhost:9000/    12-12-2020
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/3881054/13175138

Comment: thank you for reply it not answer for my question because i dont have fixed report all columns maybe change it is position

Comment: OK can you tell me how to access column as online from result

Comment: can you help me on one thing how to access column as onlineurl from code above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try adding class conditionally with `ngClass` like so:

```
<td *ngFor="let r1 of rep">
    <span [ngClass]="{'text-red': r1.columnname=='onlineurl'}">{{r1}}</span>
</td>
```

And then use CSS to apply color:

```
.text-red{
    color:red;
}
```

Comment: thank you for reply i have question How can i access column name from r1 . r1 contain data so how to access column name from r1

Comment: column name exist only on col headers so that i ask this question

Comment: From your code it seems like the header columns are still present in variable `data`. You can add the column header name to the rows object too in your `map` function I guess